# Using Interface to make a Class Trait-compatible

Tags: php, oop

Is it OK (good practice OOP wise) to make a class implement a certain interface so that a trait being used in that class can access the classes functions.

I found a SO question a few days ago with an answer explaining that traits shouldn't use methods/things from the class it's being used in. What If I made a class implement an interface so it had to have those functions that the trait uses from the class? Would that be OK. I'm taking an OOP class in university next year, so I only learned what OOP I did from the internet, in case this is a bad question. :p

So here's the idea to clarify (in PHP)

```
trait MyTrait {
  public function foo() {
    return $this->bar(); // bar is in the class the trait is to be used in
  }
}

class MyClass implements MyTraitCompatible {
  public function bar() {
    return "BAR!";
  }
}

interface MyTraitCompatible {
  public function bar();
}
```

Also, is there anyway to enforce that a class needs to implement MyTraitCompatible to use MyTrait?

**Edit**: (My actual goal is to have one function used in two classes that both extend another class (Eloquent) and would be completely identical but the function would not be used in all classes extending Eloquent - this is one way I thought of doing it.)

Comment: Seems like a logical idea to me. If you use a trait that tries to access a method that doesn't exist in the class that's using it (because it hasn't implemented your interface and doesn't know it should have that method) then you'll get a fatal error anyway

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that too, would there be any standard way to document, "hey, if you're using this trait, the class has to implement this interface."

Comment: Another idea is that in your trait's `foo()` method your first step could be `if (!in_array('MyTraitCompatible', class_implements($this, false)) { die('To use this trait you must implement MyTraitCompatible'); }`

Comment: @RobbieAverill nice idea! thanks!

Comment: Looks like [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is that your trait could [check that the class using it implements the interface](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php) you expect. [Here's an example](https://eval.in/422986) in the constructor method:

```
trait MyTrait {
    public function __construct() {
        if (!in_array('MyTraitCompatible', class_implements($this, false))) {
            throw new Exception('To use this trait you must implement MyTraitCompatible!');
        }  
    }

    public function foo() {
        return $this->bar(); // bar is in the class the trait is to be used in
    }
}
```

A valid class would be:

```
class MyClass implements MyTraitCompatible {
    use MyTrait;
    public function bar() {
        return "BAR!";
    }
}
```

An invalid class would be:

```
class InvalidClass {
    use MyTrait;
    public function baz() {
        return "I don't think so buddy.";
    }
}
```

Obviously if the class using this trait has a constructor already then this would conflict. There isn't a pretty way to avoid this since the class using the trait will have precedence over the trait and would just override it. [One option is that you could define a check method](https://eval.in/422992) in the trait and call it from the methods in the trait to check compatibility, but it's not ideal:

```
trait MyTrait {
    protected function compatible() {
        if (!in_array('MyTraitCompatible', class_implements($this, false))) {
            throw new Exception('To use this trait you must implement MyTraitCompatible!');
        }
        var_dump('Passed the test!');
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->compatible();
        return $this->bar(); // bar is in the class the trait is to be used in
    }
}
```

[You could also](https://eval.in/422995) replace that `compatible()` method with the [`__call()` magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) - but again, you might run into conflicts if you have one defined elsewhere.